# Spring rabbitMQ - transactions and transaction manager

Tags: spring, transactions, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Iv'e heard all over the internet that rabbitMQ does not support transactions.

Now, that said, spring framework provides us with a rabbit transaction manager:

here is a snippet of its definition:

```
<bean id="rabbitTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.transaction.RabbitTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

So my question is:

1) does using @transactional annotation on a method with the transaction manager actually guarantees a transaction effect?
2) how does spring managed to achieve transaction while rabbit is non transnational ?

Comment: See http://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html and http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e602.

Comment: Right, but bear in mind that there are limitations to rabbit transactions, as documented here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html but Spring AMQP ties a transactional channel into normal Spring transaction semantics (such as a publish to a rabbit template on a listener container thread use the same channel/transaction). Also, the note in Martin's reference about nacked messages going to the back of the queue is obsolete; that behavior was changed in RabbitMQ, the rolled back message now goes to the be front of the queue. I'll fix the docs.

Comment: Correction "the rolled back message" should be "the rejected message"; there is no message rollback, it's the message rejection that puts it back at the (now front) of the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbit does support local transactions. For example in a transaction if something happens in you consumer, and the received message cannot be processed the message is sent back to broker and is not consumed.

Different from other brokers (such as most of the JMS based ones) is that Rabbit does not support distributed transactions (XA transcations). This means you cannot have the same transaction when sending a message over Rabbit and persisting some data in the database.